# При сравнении двух массивов не могу правильно вывести индексы совпадающих в них элементов

Tags: javascript, массивы, индексы

Доброго времени суток уважаемые форумчане.Помогите решить проблему,я в тупике в полном и не знаю что с этим делать,буду рад любой помощи.
Суть проблемы:
есть два массива:

```
var arr1 = [1.58, 0.12, 0.1, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01];
var arr2 = [1.58, 0.1, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01];
```

Мне нужно сравнить второй массив с первым и вывести в новый массив индексы одинаковых элементов которые соответствуют индексам arr1,то есть в идеале должен получиться массив с такими индексами

```
index_etalon = [0,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11];
```

Я перерыл весь интернет в итоге нашёл вот этот код:

```
var arr1 = [1.58, 0.12, 0.1, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05,0.01];
var arr2 = [1.58, 0.1, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05,0.01];
const index_etalon = [0,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11];
var findMatch = function(arr2_Iter, arr1_Iter) {
    let ary = [];
    for(let i = 0;i < arr1_Iter.length; i++){
        for(let z = 0; z < arr2_Iter.length; z++){
            if(arr1_Iter[i] == arr2_Iter[z]){
                ary.push(i);
                arrIndexDelDuble = [...new Set(ary)];
            }
        }
    }
    return ary;
}

var indexiReal = findMatch(arr2, arr1)
```

код работает и выдаёт вот что

```
[0,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,11]
```

единственное что у меня вышло улучшить это удалить дубли и получилось так

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

но это не тот результат,в идеале должно быть так

```
index_etalon = [0,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11];
```

посмотреть что вышло вы можете тут [jsfiddle.net/navigatorus/znLptxa7/74/](https://jsfiddle.net/navigatorus/znLptxa7/74/)

У кого есть идеи или готовое решение,помогите,буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 0):

Если одного совпадения достаточно, можно перейти к следующей итерации с помощью оператора прерывания `break`:

```
var arr1 = [1.58, 0.12, 0.1, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05,0.01];
var arr2 = [1.58, 0.1, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05,0.01];
const index_etalon = [0,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11];
var findMatch = function(arr2_Iter, arr1_Iter) {
    let arr2_IterCopy=arr2_Iter.slice();
    let ary = [];
    for(let i = 0;i < arr1_Iter.length; i++){
        for(let z = 0; z < arr2_IterCopy.length; z++){
            if(arr1_Iter[i] == arr2_IterCopy[z]){
                ary.push(i);
                arr2_IterCopy.splice(z,1);
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return ary;
}

console.log(findMatch(arr2, arr1));
```

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь @Ученик ,но увы это не то,```break``` не привёл к нужному результату,теперь на выходе получаем массив с индексами ```[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]```,а в идеальном варианте он должен выглядеть так ```[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]```.

Comment: Изменил ответ, сперва не заметил из описания нюанса о количестве совпадений.